Alternatives to “Track Time in Bed with iPhone” now that it has been removed in iOS 18?
Ever since updating my iPhone 13 Pro to iOS 18 this past Monday (September 16, 2024), it seems like my sleep schedules are no longer being logged in iOS. Searches online point to “In Bed” being removed as a sleep type in iOS 18.

iOS 18 beta removed option to track time in bed with iPhone
[iOS 18.1 DB1] Time in bed via iPhone feature removed?

Apple’s official support response — as seen in the second link above is:

“After investigating your feedback, we have determined the behavior you reported will no longer be supported and therefore has been removed.”

I can still set a sleep schedule via the “Health” app and it superficially seems to work as it did in the past — with “Wind Down” and wake up working as expected — but it no longer shows the “Track Time in Bed with iPhone” option when setting a “Full Schedule” in the “Health” app. See screenshot below of what it looked like in iOS 17.x when compared to iOS 18.x:


Okay, I know that using an iPhone to track sleep wasn’t the most reliable way to track sleep, but I don’t have an Apple Watch and this has significantly impacted my ability to track basic sleep patterns.
What can be done to restore the basic functionality of the “Track Time in Bed with iPhone” without using an Apple Watch? Is there a good, basic third-party app for tracking stuff like this? Or am I stuck manually clicking “Add Data” to add “In Bed” sleep time?

Update: I ended up caving in to Apple and bought a brand new Apple Watch 10 (watchOS 11) and hope this will restore some semblance of sleep tracking to my life. Bought it for other health tracking needs as well as this sleep stuff. Yeah, “Time in Bed” is gone so it will be interesting to see all of the other sleep stages and such.

Apple acquired Beddit and now supports that app and the custom hardware sensor to allow your phone to track bed time sleep with a custom app and HealthKit integration.

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/beddit-for-model-3-5/id1411596157
https://www.beddit.com/

This sort item might be steeply discounted (You can pick these up on eBay for $30) as a used product.
I’ve tried a few sleep apps when I got my first Apple Watch and one has stood the test of time.

https://autosleepapp.tantsissa.com/home/overview

It’s designed to work even if you don’t wear a watch to bed, but I’m not sure you get good input without ever pairing a watch.
For me, wearing the watch in bed yields the best data I can get and is worth charging my watch for a while each morning and then occasionally in the evening while cooking or reading or watching a movie (couch potato hour).

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I’ve created a pair of shortcuts that can be used in automations to mimic the “In Bed” tracking behavior from prior to iOS 18. This works by recording the time when you plug your phone in while in Sleep Focus. Then when you unplug your phone, the shortcut checks for that initial recorded time. If it exists, a new “In Bed” health sample will be created in Apple Health. (Note: You don’t have to be in Sleep Focus when unplugging your phone, which allows for times when you sleep past your scheduled sleep hours.)
To install, follow the instructions below:

Install the two shortcuts from the following iCloud links.

Log In Bed
Log Out of Bed


In the Shortcuts app, open the “Log Out of Bed” shortcut by tapping the “…” in the top right corner. Scroll down to the “Log Health Sample” action. If it says “Shortcuts does not have access to your Sleep data.”, tap on “Allow Access”. Then enable the “Allow ‘Shortcuts’ to Write” access, and then tap “Allow” in the top right corner. Tap “Done” in the top right corner to exit out of the shortcut.
In the Shortcuts app, go to the Automations tab and create a new automation for “Charger”. Select “Is Connected” and  “Run Immediately”, then hit Next. Select the “Log In Bed” shortcut to run.
In the Shortcuts app, go to the Automations tab and create a new automation for “Charger”. Deselect “Is Connected” and select “Is Disconnected” and  “Run Immediately”, then hit Next. Select the “Log Out of Bed” shortcut to run.
To test that everything is working, manually turn on Sleep Focus mode, then plug your phone in. Wait a full minute, unplug your phone. When you unlock your phone, it might pop up a Privacy notification, asking if you want to share a dictionary with Health. Tap “Always Allow”. Check the Health app to see if the “In Bed” time was logged. To delete the test data, scroll to the bottom of the Sleep view in the Health app, tap Show All Data, and delete the test data.

